# AwesomeWM urxvt paste clipboard via keyboard

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, clipboard, xterm, awesome-wm

I know things similar to this have been asked many times.

I've recently made the switch from Gnome to Awesome.  My current terminal is `urxvt`.  Using the copy buffer is fine, I know I can insert into the terminal from this using `[CTRL]+[Ins]` (or middle mouse click) and do so very frequently.

The issue lies when something is in the clipboard.  I use [pass](http://www.passwordstore.org) as my password manager and when I issue the command `pass -c` this copies the password to the clipboard then wipes it after a short period of time, which I do not have a problem with.

The issue is when I am prompted for one of these passwords in the terminal.  If it was in the copy buffer I could just `[CTRL]+[Ins]` when prompted.  So the main question really becomes how do I set a keyboard combination to paste from the clipboard for urxvt/xterm?

Ideal scenario (using mysql as example):

```
$ pass -c mysql-root
Copied mysql-root to clipboard. Will clear in 45 seconds
$ mysql -uroot -p
Enter password: <keyboard combination>
root@localhost>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are perl rxvt extensions to work with the clipboard. Add this to your .Xresources file and "xrdb -merge .Xresources" before starting awesomewm

```
URxvt.perl-ext-common: default,clipboard
```

On my awesome-wm setup on FreeBSD the default is shift-ins to insert both primary and clipboard buffers. But this might be different on your os/distro.

Arch linux wiki has a detailed guide on how to set up rxvt, https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/rxvt-unicode#Cut_and_paste. The instructions can be applied on any linux distro with minor tweaks.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the correct combination for the clipboard in my environment is `[CTRL] + [ALT] + V`.

The buffer is still `[CTRL] + [Ins]`.